# I am getting issue on Admin login page using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am developing admin panel using codeigniter. How to compare the username and password form database?.Below are the code which i done but its not working. i am fresher in codeigniter.Please help me in this.....

```
    **1) view page**     
<html>
<head><title> Admin Login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

</br></br>

<div class="container row text-center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span4"></div>
      <div class="span4"><img class="center-block" src="../img/H.png" style="margin: 0 auto; width:85; height:85;" /></div>
      <div class="span4"></div>
  </div>

</br></br></br>

<form name="form" method="post" action="<?php echo site_url("home/chkLogin");?>">

<div class="fs-fields">
<input type="text" name="txtUsername" placeholder="Enter your Email ID"  id="q1" style="">

 <div class="span12"><img class="fs-fields" src="../img/line.png" style="  margin-left:10px;width:400px; height:7;" /></div>

<input type="password" name="txtPassword" placeholder="Password" id="q1" class="other">

      <div class="span4"></div>
      <div class="span4"><img class="fs-fields" src="../img/line.png" style="margin-left:10px;width:400px; height:7;" /></div>
      <div class="span4"></div>


</div>
</br>
</br>

<input  class="btn-align" type="image"   name="btnSubmit" src="../img/proceed1.png" onmouseover="this.src='../img/proceed2.png'" onmouseout="this.src='../img/proceed1.png'" >

</form>


 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>





    **2) Controller**
      ?php  
   class home extends CI_Controller  
   {  
      public function index()  
      {  
         //load the database  
         $this->load->database();  
         //loginform
         $this->load->view('login_view');

      }  
   public function chkLogin(){

    // Validate
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('txtUsername', 'Username','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('txtPassword','Password','required');

    // INPUT

    $username = $this->input->post('txtUsername');
    $password = $this->input->post('txtPassword');
    $password = md5($password);

    // VALIDATE FORM

    if( $this->form_validation->run() == FALSE ){
        // Invalid

          $this->load->view('login_view');

    }else{
        // Valid

        $this->load->model('select'); 

        if($this->select->chkLogin($username, $password)){
            // Logged In
            $this->session->set_userdata('username',$username); // SET SESSION
        }else{
            // Invalid Credentials
            $data['error']="Invalid credentials. \n Please try again !";
            $this->load->view('select_view',$data);
        }
    }
}
   } 

?>   

    **3) Model**

    <?php  
   class select extends CI_Model  
   {  
      function __construct()  
      {  
         // Call the Model constructor  
         parent::__construct();  
      }  
      //we will use the select function  



public function chkLogin($_username, $_password)
{

    $_qry = "SELECT * FROM admin_login WHERE Username = '".$_username."' AND Password = '".$_password."' ";

    $_res = $this->db->query($_qry);

    if ($_res->num_rows() > 0)
    {        
        return TRUE ;    
    }
   else 
   {
      return FALSE;
   }
}



   }  
?>
```

Comment: Read this [link](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html).It will help u in understanding.

Comment: Dude the `</br>` is wrong. It should be `<br />`...

Comment: One more thing, in your model, you have a code `return ($this->db->query($_loginqry))? TRUE : FALSE;` but what is `$_loginqry` ?

Comment: validation is not working and whatever i am typing in username and password its processing on next page .but my username and password is different in database

Answer (score 0):

Sharing code, just ask wherever needed

**VIEW :: Login**

```
form_open('Panel/chkLogin');
```

**CONTROLLER :: Class Name - Panel, Method - chkLogin**

```
/**
 * CHECK FOR LOGIN AUTHENTICATION
 */

public function chkLogin(){

    // Validate
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email','required|trim|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required|trim');

    // INPUT

    $username = $this->input->post('email');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    $password = md5($password);

    // VALIDATE FORM

    if(FALSE == $this->form_validation->run()){
        // Invalid

        $this->load->view('admin/login_page');
    }else{
        // Valid

        $this->load->model('PanelModel');
        if($this->PanelModel->chkLogin($username, $password)){
            // Logged In
            $this->session->set_userdata('username',$username); // SET SESSION
        }else{
            // Invalid Credentials
            $data['error']="Invalid credentials. \n Please try again !";
            $this->load->view('admin/login_page',$data);
        }
    }
}
```

**MODEL :: Class Name - PanelModel, Method - chkLogin**

```
/**
 * CHECK FOR LOGIN
 */

public function chkLogin($_username, $_password){

    $_qry = "SELECT * FROM backend_users WHERE email = ".$this->db->escape($_username)." AND password_hash = '".$_password."'";

    $_res = $this->db->query($_qry);

    return  ($_res->num_rows() > 0)? TRUE : FALSE;

}
```

> Feel free to clear any doubts or suggest any good code practices

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Thanks for reply sanjeev ....where is hve to insert below code in view form_open('Panel/chkLogin');

Comment: This is for codeigniter @Naren, and do double check the form and the input type names

Comment: Naren, the form_open('Panel/chkLogin') is same as <form action="Panel/chkLogin"> TO Close : use : form_close(), i'll suggest read the codeigniter user guide

Comment: hi sanjeev ...validation is not working and whatever i am typing in username and password its processing on next page .but my username and password is different in database

Comment: 1. Set $autoload['helper'] = array('form','url'); $autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session', 'table'); IN config->autoload.php 2. Use your database column name in the MODEL query Line

Comment: One more thing, in your model, you have a code return ($this->db->query($_loginqry))? TRUE : FALSE; but what is $_loginqry ?

Comment: Oopsie Naren, actually that was a query to update table for logintime you may just return TRUE in if ($_res->num_rows() > 0) block and FALSE in else BLOCK

Comment: *** Make Sure :: set_rules('email' <---- this is your form input name

Comment: And do upvote the answer if it is any help to you. Cheers !

Comment: hi sanjeev i tried your code but still not working.Please check i uploaded new code now....

Comment: Where is it going wrong? NOTE: test your code with line by line tests (a) Form HTML display okay with fields (b) Controller Method Call is okay : write simply echo 'Test Controller'; die; and so on..

Comment: same issue .whatever i am typing in username and password its going on next page ...but my username and password is different in database

Comment: Check the Model query returned result, by var_dump($_res); die;

Comment: whatever i am typing in username and password its going on next page ...but my username and password is different in database